# Background with directional arrow

Tags: android, background, android-view, layer-list

I have a quick question on how to achieve a desired view of a background on a view. What I want is a directional arrow pointing in a direction as the overlay on a background of say a textview.

For example (Beautiful MS Paint skills)

[image]

I have already tried using a layer-list which isn't going to work in this case due to screen size changes or fluctuating content heights. Is there any other possible way to do this other than using a 9patch. I've been dreading to even research 9 patches due to my complete illiteracy when it comes to graphic design.

Comment: Does the arrow need to be on different positions or can the offset from the left always be the same?

Comment: Just upwards actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this attached file would help? Created in paint, used then [draw9patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) to draw the stretchebale lines.

You might have seen the docs for [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch).

[image: Created with paint, edited in draw9patch - 2 mins]

Comment: Just tried that out and yes thats exactly what I want now I just have to find a way to make it on my own shrink the arrow and move it more to the left. Thank you though the solution is to use a 9patch

Answer (score 1):

Actually this can work in a layer list. just from the top of my head you could do soemthing like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

   <item android:left="10dp"> <!-- offset from the left -->
       <bitmap android:src="@drawable/arrow_icon"/>
   </item>

   <item android:top="5dp"> <!-- replace with the hight of your arrow -->
       <shape> <solid android:src="#FFFFFF"/> </shape>
   </item>

</layer-list>
```

Save it in your `res/drawable` as `with_arrow.xml` and then you can use it like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/with_arrow"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"/> <!-- should be AT LEAST the height of your arrow, might want to increase it a bit though -->
```

If you set this as the background of your textview for instance it should stretch it with the content.

On another note you should really look into 9-patching. It's really not that complicated
see here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: The reason that I believe a layer-list won't work is say for example you put that as the background of a textview and your arrow is say 30px by 30px (xhdpi), A) there is no way to push it to the top of the background (you can try android:gravity="top|left" on the bitmap, the outcome isn't as expected) and you are setting the offset of the background to be pushed down now your TextView will be  between the blank arrow space and the background space. I think I will just have to refer to a 9patch sadly.

Comment: Yeah i should've mentioned that you need to add more padding to the top to align with the text below the arrow. if you add at least android:paddingTop="5dp" the text should align right

Comment: Added an example for clarity