# TextView custom design without image

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to create one custom textview which will look like as following.
[image]

But i want to create this without using any image at bottom. I found one SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829022/background-with-directional-arrow)  but it's suggest [9Patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) which i don't want to use.

We can create custom stroke, padding for this but i am not getting how i can create this.

I don't have any code to show you but that's not mean i didn't try anything.

Please give me hint or reference.

Thank you...

Comment: So, you don't want to use a 9 patch... Then I really don't know how to help you. Surely, not using an xml drawable!

Comment: You can use a drawable for that (png), use padding to position the text.

Comment: see 9 patch image is a good option as the Text in your Textview will not have a fixed length and if you use normal image then it will not be able to adjust as per the text length.Use 9 patch image.Give this image to a style give that style to your textview.This is the solution according to me.All the best :)

Comment: Than design a shape as xml file under drawable and use it as a background. ex: `<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    
    <gradient
         android:startColor="#ad6800"
         android:centerColor="#f8c400"
         android:endColor="#eda000"
         android:angle="90" />

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#faac00" />
     <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="6dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="6dp"
        android:topRightRadius="6dp" />

</shape>`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this image as the background of the textview

Comment: It will stretch in a **very ugly** shape.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new custom.xml file under drawables

Try something like this

`<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@color/color_black" />
    <solid android:color="@color/color_white" />
</shape>`

and then apply new style to your layout background

`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/custom.xml"
    android:orientation="vertical" >`